# No Mans's Sky galactic map details

Tags: no-mans-sky

Has anyone found out what the galactic map looks like in the final version? Is there a search function for stellar bodies, I.E. can I find a certain solar system and figure out how to fly to it, similar to Elite: Dangerous? Are there any parameters for stars that can be set to find only certain planets or stars? I want to find some general knowledge since the wiki is still in it's infancy.

Comment: I mean, I'm guessing the answer to this is "not yet". I do know that there's no way to specifically fly to a specific system, nor specifically search for things without just panning through the map.

Answer (score 1):

As the game as been out for a while, I'm going you assume this question has been answered by the wiki.

For those who are wondering, the answer is **no.** There is currently no way to search the galaxy, aside from the left/right on the d-pad after searching for discoveries, which shows you discoveries nearby from other players. There is also no way to set waypoints to things you have already discovered, nor planets, unless you can find them on the galactic map, in which case you can by pressing square.